# Comparing and Updating multiple excel sheets within a single workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 4 sheets of names, some of which may exist in one or more of the other sheets. What I need to do is, compare all 4 sheets of names and create a new sheet ( Master List ) of all names from each of the sheets, removing any duplicates at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this so far. This is a Q & A site, so you need to ask a specific question related to where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

An extremely useful article can be found [here](http://www.bighungrygeek.com/merge-worksheets-in-excel/)

**In a nutshell:**

1. Ensure that the worksheets you intend to merge all have the same
   columns and rows in the same order.
2. Create the Merged Master worksheet. This worksheet should look
   identical to the other worksheets
3. Navigate to Data → Consolidate.
4. In the Consolidate dialog box that appears, under Function, choose
   the summary function that you want Excel to use to consolidate your
   data.
5. Click reference select first range
6. Click reference select second range
7. Repeat for all ranges
8. Click OK to complete the merge

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.